# Can I turn off "Activity for Jobs" in the Jobs tab

Tags: rundeck

Is there a setting to have the "Activity for Jobs" section of the Jobs page minimized by default, or have it default to "The past hour", or otherwise control the pagination separately from the job list pagination? This is for Rundeck 3.1.x since I believe this was minimized in Rundeck 2.x by default.

We've been playing with rundeck.gui.paginatejobs.max.per.page, but this changes both jobs and activity listing. I'd like to see mainly jobs on this page since we have a separate tab for activity.

Answer (score 0):

No seems possible right now, [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/gui-customization.html) you've all GUI customization parameters for Rundeck and none point to hide "Activity for Jobs". You can suggest it as enhancement [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).